# Mysql Foreach from one table to another

Tags: mysql, select, foreach

I have 2 tables, First table is user and second table is user_attendance.

In the user attendance I'm inserting IN and OUT per line, so 1 line for IN and 1 line for OUT.

I want a MySQL select(so I don't have to do it on Php) which will loop for every ID in users and get the last OUT and first IN of that user in user table.

I tried doing it on Php by selecting first all the ID in user and looping it Via php and Select the 1st in and Last out of that Id in attendance. Like so.

```
$userCreds = DB::table('users')->select('user_id', 'username')->get();

$emailBody = '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Employee ID</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Date</th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

        foreach ($userCreds as $userCred) {
           $userAttendance = DB::select( 
                            DB::raw(
                                "SELECT username,
                                    (
                                        SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time(b.server_time), '%r')
                                        FROM `users` a
                                        LEFT JOIN user_attendance b
                                        ON a.user_id = b.user_id
                                        WHERE a.user_id = $userCred->user_id
                                        AND (b.server_time between '$ysDate' and '$yeDate')
                                        AND b.action = 'IN' ORDER BY b.server_time ASC LIMIT 1
                                    ) as TimeIn,
                                    (
                                        SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time(b.server_time), '%r')
                                        FROM `users` a
                                        LEFT JOIN user_attendance b
                                        ON a.user_id = b.user_id
                                        WHERE a.user_id = $userCred->user_id
                                        AND (b.server_time between '$ysDate' and '$yeDate')
                                        AND b.action = 'OUT' ORDER BY b.server_time DESC LIMIT 1
                                    ) as TimeOut
                                FROM users
                                WHERE user_id = $userCred->user_id"
                            )
                        ); 

            $emailBody .= '<tr><td>'.$userCred->user_id.'</td><td>'.$userCred->username.'</td><td>'.date('Y-m-d',(strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $date) ) )).'</td><td>'.$userAttendance[0]->TimeIn.'</td><td>'.$userAttendance[0]->TimeOut.'</td></tr>';
        }
```

Instead of doing it on Php, I want it to be done on the Mysql side so I can actually create a view which will be stored ever now and done for recording purposes.

What I need is like this

**user table**

user_id | username

01   | piglet

02   | pooh

03   | tiger

**user_attendance table**

user_id |      servertime      | action

01   | 2019-10-10 08:00:00  |   IN

01   | 2019-10-10 09:00:00  |   OUT

01   | 2019-10-10 10:00:00  |   IN

01   | 2019-10-10 18:00:00  |   OUT

02   | 2019-10-10 07:45:00  |   IN

02   | 2019-10-10 09:00:00  |   OUT

02   | 2019-10-10 10:00:00  |   IN

02   | 2019-10-10 19:50:00  |   OUT

Result will be

user_id  |    date    |    IN    |     OUT

01    | 2019-20-10 | 08:00:00 |  18:00:00

02    | 2019-20-10 | 07:45:00 |  19:50:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the refactored `sql` query.

first is to get your users table
second is the join the `IN` time
third is to join the `OUT` time
fourth is get the `max()` and `min()` time of user id then group by a.user_id.

```
SELECT a.user_id, TIME_FORMAT(time(min(b.server_time)), '%r') as TimeIn, TIME_FORMAT(time(max(c.server_time)), '%r') as TimeOut
FROM `users` a
LEFT JOIN user_attendance b ON a.user_id = b.user_id and (b.server_time between '$ysDate' and '$yeDate') and b.action = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN user_attendance c ON a.user_id = c.user_id and (c.server_time between '$ysDate' and '$yeDate') and c.action = 'OUT'
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

Comment: It's working but I need only to select the first IN and last OUT

Comment: @TheOneNewbie, try now, added select case in order by

Comment: haha, @TheOneNewbie, seems you just want the min() and max() of each employee id

Comment: how about my second question Metal : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501117/mysql-foreach-from-one-table-to-another-part-2

Comment: @TheOneNewbie, so this one should be within 5 days or past 5 days?