# Mysql Foreach from one table to another Part 2

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, join, select

This has connection with my previous question

[Mysql Foreach from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496561/mysql-foreach-from-one-table-to-another)

I managed to get the everyday logs but what I'm stuck now is how to get everyday logs for the past 5 days with the format same as the format for single day

```
SELECT a.user_id AS EmployeeId, a.username AS EmployeeName, DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)) as Date, TIME_FORMAT(time(min(b.server_time)), '%r') AS 'IN', TIME_FORMAT(time(max(c.server_time)), '%r') as 'OUT'
FROM `users` a
LEFT JOIN user_attendance b ON a.user_id = b.user_id and (b.server_time BETWEEN 
CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 00:00:00') and CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 23:59:59')) and b.action = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN user_attendance c ON a.user_id = c.user_id and (b.server_time BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 00:00:00') and CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 23:59:59')) and c.action = 'OUT'
GROUP BY a.username, a.user_id
```

The code above is for daily logs. I need to get the 5 days with the same format

**User table**

```
userID | username
01     | tiger
02     | pooh
```

**user_attendance**

```
user_id | dateTime            | action
01      | 2019-10-01 08:00:00 | IN
01      | 2019-10-01 08:45:00 | OUT
01      | 2019-10-01 10:00:00 | IN
01      | 2019-10-01 14:00:00 | OUT
01      | 2019-10-02 08:00:00 | IN
01      | 2019-10-02 08:45:00 | OUT
01      | 2019-10-02 10:00:00 | IN
01      | 2019-10-02 14:00:00 | OUT
02      | 2019-10-01 08:00:00 | IN
02      | 2019-10-01 08:45:00 | OUT
02      | 2019-10-01 10:00:00 | IN
02      | 2019-10-01 14:00:00 | OUT
02      | 2019-10-02 08:00:00 | IN
02      | 2019-10-02 08:45:00 | OUT
02      | 2019-10-02 10:00:00 | IN
02      | 2019-10-02 14:00:00 | OUT
```

**Result I'm expecting**

```
user_id | username | IN                  | OUT
01      | tiger    | 2019-10-01 08:00:00 | 2019-10-01 14:00:00
01      | tiger    | 2019-10-02 08:00:00 | 2019-10-02 14:00:00
02      | tiger    | 2019-10-01 08:00:00 | 2019-10-01 14:00:00
02      | tiger    | 2019-10-02 08:00:00 | 2019-10-02 14:00:00
```

Comment: this is within 5 days or the past 5 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
    min(case when a.action = 'IN' then a.dateTime end) `in`,
    max(case when a.action = 'OUT' then a.dateTime end) `out`
from 
    user u
    inner join user_attendance a on u.user_id = a.user_id
group by
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
    date(a.dateTime)
order by
    u.user_id,
    date(a.dateTime)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eHNcMXJzE7ooEtDafvfHQ/2)**:

```
| user_id | username | in                  | out                 |
| ------- | -------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1       | tiger    | 2019-10-01 08:00:00 | 2019-10-01 14:00:00 |
| 1       | tiger    | 2019-10-02 08:00:00 | 2019-10-02 14:00:00 |
| 2       | pooh     | 2019-10-01 08:00:00 | 2019-10-01 14:00:00 |
| 2       | pooh     | 2019-10-02 08:00:00 | 2019-10-02 14:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `- interval 5 day` on your condition

```
SELECT a.user_id AS EmployeeId, a.username AS EmployeeName
    , DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)) as Date, TIME_FORMAT(time(min(b.server_time)), '%r') AS 'IN'
    , TIME_FORMAT(time(max(c.server_time)), '%r') as 'OUT'
FROM `users` a
LEFT JOIN user_attendance b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
    and (b.server_time BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 00:00:00') - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 23:59:59')) 
    and b.action = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN user_attendance c ON a.user_id = c.user_id 
    and (c.server_time BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 00:00:00') - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CONCAT(DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)), ' 23:59:59')) 
    and c.action = 'OUT'
GROUP BY a.username, a.user_id
```

you can also use `curdate()` function instead of `now()` to get only the date without time.

```
SELECT a.user_id AS EmployeeId, a.username AS EmployeeName
    , DATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),1)) as Date, TIME_FORMAT(time(min(b.server_time)), '%r') AS 'IN'
    , TIME_FORMAT(time(max(c.server_time)), '%r') as 'OUT'
FROM `users` a
LEFT JOIN user_attendance b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
    and b.server_time BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND curdate()  
    and b.action = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN user_attendance c ON a.user_id = c.user_id 
    and c.server_time BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND curdate()  
    and c.action = 'OUT'
GROUP BY a.username, a.user_id
```